# what is the second parameter of dataobjectmethod, asp.net BLL

Tags: asp.net, bll

I'm studying BLL of data access in asp.net.

just one thing not clear, what is the second parameter of DataObjectMethod which is a boolean variable called isDefault.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of data source controls, you can have multiple select methods.  Setting is default means that this is the primary one it will use, unless another is specified.  See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ad99k3d(v=vs.100).aspx